# Javascript, variables and if/else statements

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

I'm a complete Javascript newbie and I'm helping my friend with a small project for college.

The idea is that when a checkbox is checked an item is chosen, and then when a "total" button is pressed, the sum of the checked items is printed. I've been using if/else statements so if checked `var staticprice = 29.00` and else `var staticprice = 0.00`, which appears to work fine until I total it. Adding the variable "staticprice" always returns a value of 0.00, even when checked.

It's very messy (as is my first attempt creating something like this): http://jsfiddle.net/mNmQs/180/

What am I missing here?

Cheers

Comment: -1 because searching SO witn 'Javascript, variables and if/else statements' gives me 1'840 results!!

Comment: Apologies. It's my first time here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things to make life easier, give your checkboxes a `value`, that is what it's there for! I've updated your fiddle to include the appropriate values per checkbox. The next is loops, simply loop your checkboxes, if checked, add the `value` of the checked input to the total:

```
var totalBtn = document.getElementById("total"),
checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

totalBtn.onclick = function() {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            total = total + parseInt(checkboxes[i].value);
        }
    }

    alert(total);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mNmQs/181/

Comment: Slightly updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mNmQs/182/ to show how to render the int total the same way as the original question

Comment: Thankyou to these comments! You really helped me out! I merged the two to get this which does exactly what I want it to!
http://jsfiddle.net/mNmQs/185/

Answer (score 2):

You could change this line:

```
this.grandTotal= +seaprice + +stillprice + +staticprice;
```

To:

```
grandTotal= parseInt(seaprice,10) + parseInt(stillprice,10) + parseInt(staticprice,10);
```

In this case the problem is that you're trying to sum strings instead of numbers

**[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/hwSQ3/)**

**HOWEVER** it seems in this case there's no point in declaring your prices as strings. **Of course unless** you wanted to show the prices with in the format `0.00`, otherwise just declare them as numbers and that should be better, like: `var seaprice = 39.00;` or `var seaprice = 39.00;` instead of `var seaprice = "39.00";`

**[Other fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/hwSQ3/2/)**

Comment: Wouldn't it make a lot more sense to declare them as ints instead of parsing them?

Comment: @ElatedOwl It makes more sense unless the OP wants to show the prices like `X.XX` instead of just `X`...